# Does Angular have anything similar to the way d3 does joins?

Tags: angular

[d3](https://d3js.org/) has a neat and declarative way of handing updating data, which it refers to as a "join". It allows you to define what happens when datapoints exit, enter and change in the data you bind to a visualisation. One of the best bits is that you can define a function to get a key from each datapoint on which to identify that the same datapoints have changed. One of the main developers of d3 has a really good explanation of it [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

In Angular I might want a parent component to have an observable that emits arrays of widgets, and then based on those widgets I might want to render children. A join would be handy here, since I don't want to destroy widget components that really only need updating with different widget properties. I can implement the join myself, but is there something in Angular (or perhaps another package) more declarative that might help me? I'm trying to keep my code as reactive as possible.

I'm relatively new to Angular, so I'm open to suggestions of completely different ways of thinking about it that will still achieve nice reactive code. Thanks for any help in advance!